# Query generate all month via date create in mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table like this

```
id | staff_id | total_leave |   date_create
---+---------+--------+-----------
 1 |       1 |     15   | 01-01-2015
 2 |       2 |     17   | 01-01-2015
 3 |       3 |     25   | 01-01-2015
 4 |       1 |     34   | 01-02-2015
 5 |       2 |     37   | 01-02-2015
 6 |       3 |     31   | 01-02-2015
 7 |       1 |     45   | 01-03-2015
 8 |       2 |     48   | 01-03-2015
 9 |       3 |     50   | 01-03-2015
```

I want display like below

```
Staff 1
Jan    |    Feb    |   Mar
-------+-----------+-------
15          34         45

Staff 2
Jan    |    Feb    |   Mar
-------+-----------+-------
17          37         48
```

is there a way to do because I don't know how to write mysql display report that.

Thanks for advance

Comment: What if there's a row with date `01-01-2014`? It should be grouped together with `01-01-2015 - 31-01-2015`?

Comment: only current year 2015.

Comment: please explain more its bit confusing ...you want data group by date and staff id ?

Comment: I want display total leave follow each month by staff id. those data will insert beginner of month

Comment: Store dates using a date data type. Then get back to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or maybe more elegant report like this

```
staff_id  January  February  March   April   May     June    July    August  September  October  November  December  
--------  -------  --------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  -------  --------  ----------
       1  15       34        45                                                                                      
       2  17       37        48                                                                                      
       3  25       31        50
```

you can get by this query

```
SELECT staff_id, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT staff_id, 
        IF(jan IS NULL, '', jan) AS January,
        IF(feb IS NULL, '', feb) AS February,
        IF(mar IS NULL, '', mar) AS March,
        IF(apr IS NULL, '', apr) AS April,
        IF(may IS NULL, '', may) AS May,
        IF(jun IS NULL, '', jun) AS June,
        IF(jul IS NULL, '', jul) AS July,
        IF(aug IS NULL, '', aug) AS August,
        IF(sep IS NULL, '', sep) AS September,
        IF(octo IS NULL, '', octo) AS October,
        IF(nov IS NULL, '', nov) AS November,
        IF(dece IS NULL, '', dece) AS December
    FROM(
    SELECT main.staff_id,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 1 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS jan,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 2 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS feb,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 3 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS mar,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 4 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS apr,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 5 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS may,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 6 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS jun,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 7 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS jul,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 8 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS aug,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 9 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS sep,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 10 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS octo,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 11 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS nov,
        (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 12 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS dece
    FROM your_table AS main
    ) AS report_sub
    ORDER BY staff_id
) AS final_report
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    staff_id, MONTHNAME(date_create) as month, SUM(total_leave) as total
FROM
    table_name
WHERE 
    YEAR(date_create) = 2015
GROUP BY MONTH(date_create), staff_id  DESC
```

[Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0179/4).

Comment: I'm curious how u manage to switch date in the correct format (because i did it manually). Is there a way to swap them in fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
SELECT monthname (date_create), total_leave
FROM name_table 
WHERE staff_id = 1 and year(date_create) = 2015
```

I did an example here :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47bdb/10/0

Output :

```
monthname(date_create)  total_leave
January                     15
February                    34
March                       45
```

Edit : updated query for the current year only.

Comment: I want to date_create as column name and total leave will show in each month

Comment: updated but have no clues about using date_create as column_name using mysql only.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution I can suggest for your case

```
SELECT IF(0 != CEIL(staff_id) - staff_id, CAST(staff_id + 0.1 AS UNSIGNED), '') AS staff_id, January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT `staff_id` - 0.1 AS staff_id, 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
FROM your_table
UNION 
SELECT staff_id, 
    IF(jan IS NULL, '', jan),
    IF(feb IS NULL, '', feb),
    IF(mar IS NULL, '', mar),
    IF(apr IS NULL, '', apr),
    IF(may IS NULL, '', may),
    IF(jun IS NULL, '', jun),
    IF(jul IS NULL, '', jul),
    IF(aug IS NULL, '', aug),
    IF(sep IS NULL, '', sep),
    IF(octo IS NULL, '', octo),
    IF(nov IS NULL, '', nov),
    IF(dece IS NULL, '', dece)
FROM(
SELECT main.staff_id,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 1 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS jan,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 2 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS feb,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 3 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS mar,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 4 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS apr,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 5 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS may,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 6 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS jun,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 7 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS jul,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 8 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS aug,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 9 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS sep,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 10 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS octo,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 11 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS nov,
    (SELECT total_leave FROM your_table AS sub WHERE MONTH(date_create) = 12 AND sub.staff_id = main.staff_id) AS dece
FROM your_table AS main
) AS report_sub
ORDER BY staff_id
) AS final_report
```

it will give you a report like this

```
staff_id  January  February  March   April   May     June    July    August  September  October  November  December  
--------  -------  --------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ------  ---------  -------  --------  ----------
1         January  February  March   April   May     June    July    August  September  October  November  December  
          15       34        45                                                                                      
2         January  February  March   April   May     June    July    August  September  October  November  December  
          17       37        48                                                                                      
3         January  February  March   April   May     June    July    August  September  October  November  December  
          25       31        50
```